# App crashing right away after starting service via ContextCompat.startForegroundService()

Tags: android, android-intentservice, foreground-service

My app is for now still targeting SDK 25
I'm trying to replace my background services in order to be able to target SDK 26.
In order to do so I now start my IntentService with

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService()
```

If I understand the documentation correctly I then have 5 seconds to call startForeground() on the service.

When doing so it works fine.
But sometimes my service doesn't have any work to do, so it just exits right away (onHandleIntent() doesn't do anything) and yet the app crashes with the following error

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
Process: com.myAPPPackage, PID: 3855
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

What about the 5 seconds delay in that case?
I can see that the service onDestroy() method is called like a few ms after the call to   ContextCompat.startForegroundService()

Any idea why the app is crashing like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why the app is crashing like that?

You are not calling `startForeground()`.

> But sometimes my service doesn't have any work to do, so it just exits right away

You need to call `startForeground()` first.

Or have whatever it is that is calling `startForegroundService()` determine whether there is any work to do first, before calling `startForegroundService()`. That way, you do not have to bother calling `startForegroundService()` if there is no need for a foreground service.

> If I understand the documentation correctly I then have 5 seconds to call startForeground() on the service.

Yes, but that does not mean that you can *skip* calling `startForeground()`. You *must* call `startForeground()`. You just have five seconds in which to do so. My guess is that this is to avoid an avenue of abuse for `startForegroundService()`.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks